# read with an hyphen fails while read with an underscore succeeds

Tags: bash, read

On a CentOS with Bash 5.0.17 I try to execute:

```
read x-y
```

> `` -bash: read: `x-y': not a valid identifier ``

```
read x_y
```

**Success**: No error and the variable is saved.

---

What might cause that problem and how would you suggest to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions) states that a valid variable name is

> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore.

So `x-y` is not a valid variable name and cannot be used as argument of `read`.